# Why does Zen 2012 Black Edition change my cell colours when I save as jpeg or png?

Tags: colors, export

My cells are blue in the original and stay that way when I save as LSM.  But when I save as JPEG or PNG, all of the sudden the blue cells are now green, and any green parts are now red, in the exported image (although the JPEG/PNG still being viewed in Zen looks correct.)  How can I get it to leave my colours as they are?  Does Blue edition do this too?  (I don't want to have to reinstall to get blue edition if I don't have to.)

Carl Zeiss Zen 2012 Black SP1.

Comment: In eight hours you will be able to write an answer.  http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, inexplicable to me, but if you go File->Export (and leave defaults) rather than File->Save As, it looks right.

Comment: Generally the "export" option in programs is meant for saving for use outside of the program, where as Save/Save As is meant to save to be opened in the same program later. So that makes sense, I suppose.